# Compare Array of Strings and return the smallest one

Tags: java, arrays, string, recursion, compareto

I am implementing a code to Compare `Array` of `Strings` and return the smallest one using `stringONE.compareTo(stringTwo)`.

The code will use recursion to alternate through the `Array` instead of a for loop.

- I implemented the code so that the compare method keeps calling itself with the different parameters until it reaches the end of the `Array` then the exception handling will exit the recursion.

  the problem is that: it keeps iterating until it reaches a stack overflow without triggering `outofboundsException`.

below is my code then you can test:

code:

```
public class recursivefindMinimum {
    public static String [] stringArray = {"delta","alpha","omega","zeta"};
    public static String result;

    public static void main (String[]args) {
        System.out.println("result :  "+findMinimum(stringArray, 0, 1));
    }

    public static String findMinimum(String[] stringArray, int index1, int index2) {
        int number = stringArray[index1].compareTo(stringArray[index2]);

        if (number< 0) {
            findMinimum(stringArray,index1,index2++); zebobi="delta1";
        }
        else if (number> 0) {
            findMinimum(stringArray,index2,index2++);zebobi="delta2";
        }
        else if (number== 0) {
            findMinimum(stringArray,index1,index2++);zebobi="delta3";
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(index1);
        System.out.println(index2);
        result= stringArray[index1]

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This won't compile: you're missing a semicolon and can't `catch` without `try`. I'd also recommend putting global variables inside the `main` scope.

Answer (score 2):

In recursion you have to always have a base case, which is a point where you stop the recursion. At the moment you have recursive cases for every possible outcome:

```
if (number< 0){
     findMinimum(stringArray,index1,index2++); zebobi="delta1";
}
else if (number> 0){
     findMinimum(stringArray,index2,index2++);zebobi="delta2";
}
else if (number== 0){
     findMinimum(stringArray,index1,index2++);zebobi="delta3";
}
```

(When `number` is less than, more than, or equal to zero) So your method will always be calling itself, which is infinite recursion. You need to include a base case that will stop the recursion

Also it would probably be best to make `result` a variable only declared in the scope of `findMinimum()`. Then you would need to change your recursive calls to `result = findMinimum(...)`

The base case for this problem is when one of the index variables will go out of bounds.

```
public static String findMinimum(String[] stringArray, int index1, int index2) 
{
    String result = "";
    if(index1 > stringArray.length || index2 > stringArray.length-1) {
        return stringArray[index2-1];
    }

    int number = stringArray[index1].compareTo(stringArray[index2]);


    if (number< 0){
        result = findMinimum(stringArray,index1,index2+1); zebobi="delta1";
    }
    else if (number> 0){
        result = findMinimum(stringArray,index2,index2+1);zebobi="delta2";
    }
    else if (number== 0){
        result = findMinimum(stringArray,index1,index2+1);zebobi="delta3";
    }

    return result;
 }
```

---

If you are trying to trigger an exception and then return from the exception block:

-You need to add a `try` block (You can't have a catch without a try)

-You need to pass `index2 + 1` instead of `index2++`

-You need to return `stringArray[index2]` instead of `stringArray[index1]`

```
public static String findMinimum(String[] stringArray, int index1, int index2) 
{
    String result;
    int number = stringArray[index1].compareTo(stringArray[index2]);

    try {
        if (number< 0){
        result = findMinimum(stringArray,index1,index2+1); zebobi="delta1";}

        else if (number> 0){
        result = findMinimum(stringArray,index2,index2+1);zebobi="delta2";}

        else if (number== 0){
        result = findMinimum(stringArray,index1,index2+1);zebobi="delta3";}

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(index1);
        System.out.println(index2);
        result= stringArray[index2]; 
    }
    return result;
}
```

***Output:***

```
result :  zeta
```

Comment: I understand better now. I thought outofboundsException will stop the alteration. however, when the exception handling is done it returns to where it was. I wonder what should I use as a base case

Comment: You still need to declare result (or just return directly everywhere). Also, the return in the catch block seems to be redundant

Comment: @StefanHaustein The OP had `result` declared as a `static` variable. Thank you for the suggestion about the redundant return statement. I removed it

Comment: ugh... with a static result you don't need the assignments in the if branches though... O:)

Comment: @GBlodgett Yes, this is Java.

Comment: If result is static, this means there is only one value that is shared everywhere. So as soon as it is assigned in the recursive function, it's accessible outside the function and does not need to be returned. Typically one would prefer functions to be as isolated as possible -- if feasible only operate on the inputs and return the result (opposed to writing to global state) because this ensures that the function can easily be re-used in other contexts and that reasoning about the function can be limited to the function

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possible solution that would avoid those problems with indexes:

```java
public static String findMinimumRecursive(String[] array, String currentMinString){
  if(array.length == 0)
    return currentMinString;

  return findMinimumRecursive(
              Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 1, array.length), 
              ((Integer)currentMinString.length()).compareTo(array[0].length()) < 0 ? currentMinString : array[0]);
}
```

You could then call this function like:

```
String[] arr = {"abc", "abcd", "ab", "abe"};
String result = findMinimumRecursive(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 1, arr.length), arr[0]);
```

This function would evaluate the current minimum length string with the first element of the array, and everytime it will call itself with the same array with the element that was evaluated removed and with the current minimum string.
The stop condition is the input array is empty where it would just return the current minimum length string which corresponds to the minimum length of all the string of the array

The calls would then look like this:

1. findMinimumRecursivly(["abcd", "ab", "abe"], "abc")
2. findMinimumRecursivly(["ab", "abe"], "abc")
3. findMinimumRecursivly(["abe"], "ab")
4. findMinimumRecursivly(["abe"], "a")
5. findMinimumRecursivly([], "a")

Note that the method Arrays.copyOfRange, creates an array with the same elements as the 1st argument but only from the start and end index on the 2nd and 3rd parameter - see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(T[],%20int,%20int)